# Preg_replace content with mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a replacement function. I have data in a db with a field 'content' that returns the content for a page. In that content I have a url tag like `<a href="[2]">title</a>`. The number between the [brackets] is the page_id of my pages table.

I have a function called replaceContent:

```
function replaceContent($content,$mysqli){
    $search = "/(\[)(.*?)(\])/";
 
    $newContent = preg_replace($search,makeUrl('$2',$mysqli),$content);
    return $newContent;
}
```

in that function I have a function called makeUrl:

```
function makeUrl($id,$mysqli){
    $query = "SELECT url FROM pages WHERE id = '".$id."' ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $data = $result -> fetch_assoc();
    return $data['url'];
}
```

What I tried:

- When I call the function `makeUrl(2,$mysqli)` standalone, it works fine and returns the url.
- When I change the return in the makeUrl function with 'abc $id' the `replaceContent` function replaces the url with 'abc 2'

But together I get a blank return...

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group references (e.g. `$2`) are parsed in any replacement **strings**, but you're replacing with the return value of a function. So you're litereally passing along `$2` as the argument, not `2`.

Instead, feed the matches to a callback.

```
preg_replace_callback($search, function($match) use($mysqli) {
    return makeUrl($match[2], $mysqli)
}, $content)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I changed the makeUrl return with a query return. With the total package I get a good query,  when I do makeUrl('$3',$mysqli); I get SELECT url FROM pages WHERE id = '$3', so I don't think this is the problem..

Comment: But you are right! It works, It was so strange, I got the right query, but in the result output I got zero num_rows. Now it works! Thanks

Comment: Yes because you were passing along a literal `$2`, as I say, not the result of the replacement. Ergo, it was looking for a record in the DB with ID = "$2", and finding none.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know as not tested but I'd guess you can use `preg_replace_callback` with your `makeUrl` function passed into the callback.

```
function replaceContent( $content,$mysqli ){
    $search = "/(\[)(.*?)(\])/";
    $callback=function($matches){
        return makeUrl( $matches[0], $mysqli );
    }
    return  preg_replace_callback( $search, $callback, $content );
}


function makeUrl( $id=false,$mysqli ){
    if( empty( $id ) or !is_integer( $id ) )return false;
    
    $query = 'SELECT `url` FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = ?';
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
    
    $result=$stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result( $url );
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();

    return $url;
}
```